# Why VBA does not create file via external .exe file?

Tags: vba, excel, shell

I have this testing program written in C#. It simply creates a text file in directory where this exe file is.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string exactPath = Path.GetFullPath("test.txt");
            File.Create(exactPath);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Now VBA is running it by Call Shell

```
    strProgramName = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\test.exe"
    Call Shell("" & strProgramName & "")
```

Everything seems fine. Except it does not create any file and it should. If I run it manually it does creates a file.

MS documentation for Shell states that :

> The Shell function requires unmanaged code permission, which might
>   affect its execution in partial-trust situations. For more
>   information, see SecurityPermission and Code Access Permissions.

So I think that somehow my test.exe does not have permission to create a file.

Comment: what is the value of `strProgramName` just before the `Shell` call? (side question: why would you use [*Systems Hungarian*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) in VBA but not in C#?)

Comment: Is the C# executable in the `strProgramName` location? If you attach a debugger to the EXCEL.EXE process, do you hit a breakpoint in `Main`? Does the console appear?

Comment: Do you intend to wrap `strProgramName` in quotes? If so, you need to have `"""" & strProgramName & """"` (quadruple quotes on each end). Two quotes is just an empty string.

Comment: Dim strProgramName As String. Yes executable is in right location because console does appear as it should. Even with quadruple quotes it does not work.

Comment: As noted in the [VBA documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278437.aspx) for `Shell`, look at the return value from Shell to see if the program executed successfully. A return value of zero indicates an error

Comment: When I MsgBox that return value it indeed shows some task ID number and not 0.